# OData v4.0 - How can I use the support for $crossjoin?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to use a support for $crossjoin follow as [http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326314]

E.g. ~/$crossjoin(Products,Sales)?$filter=Products/ID eq Sales/ProductID

I have investigated some references and source code:

**WebApi** and **odata.net** [https://github.com/OData]

But I've yet to find the support for $crossjoin, the **ODataPathHandler** cannot parse URI to ODataPath contains $crossjoin. I'm not sure that I didn't miss any configuration.

Please give me your advice.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported yet, please track on this issue:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/789

Contribution is warmly welcome!

Comment: Thanks. I will try to customize :).