# How to set up an Odata service that supports $crossjoin, hosted on ASP.net core or separately

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

I'm working on a new web application in ASP.net core and currently use the [OData WebApi](https://github.com/OData/WebApi). The issue I'm currently having is that one OData feature I want to use **[$Crossjoin](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752354)** is [not supported by the web api.](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/789) Also noted in [this question from 2 years ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842102/odata-v4-0-how-can-i-use-the-support-for-crossjoin) And I have not seen any updates since.

Essentially I want to be able to use a query like this with Odata and have my application hosted on ASP.net Core:

```
http://host/service/$crossjoin(Products,Sales)?
                                    $filter=Products/ID eq Sales/ProductID
```

So right now I'm assuming there is no way to get **$Crossjoin** to work with WebAPI. Are there any libraries that will support that protocol and can also be hosted on ASP.net core or at the same time? One that I came across [OData V4 Service modules - SQL Connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-mssql) that I can host using node.

The reason why I would like to use **Crossjoin** is because I cannot modify tables or add views to the database I am accessing. It does not use Primary or Foreign Keys. And I will want to be be able to join on multiple properties. I am also early into building my application so I don't mind migrating my current WebApi to something else to save me time in the future.

To have an idea of how my application looks, it is based off the [ASP.NET Core Vue Starter template with Typescript.](https://github.com/SoftwareAteliers/asp-net-core-vue-starter) I am also using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, and Entity Framework Core.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.